# Is there a way to use my iPhone 5's unlimited data on my iPad mini Wi-Fi without the expensive hotspot option?

Tags: iphone, ipad, internet-sharing, cellular-data

I am grand-fathered in the AT&T unlimited data.  I sometimes like to stream Netflix, Hulu, etc while on lunch break.  Is there a way to airplay it over to my iPad mini, or do some type of internet sharing without paying the ridiculous data rates for sharing and AT&T?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have been hacks in the past to enable tethering, but in almost all cases, the carrier can tell what you are doing. I have even heard that people that tethered were individually contacted by AT&T to let them know that the tethering fee would be added if they wished to continue tethering and asked the customers to come in to chat if there were perhaps a misunderstanding.

You'll want to look for an unofficial AirPlay receiver app on the jailbreak side of things since Apple isn't even [allowing these for solid commercial sound apps](http://www.imore.com/apple-clamping-airplay-receiver-apps-including-rogue-amoebas-airfoil) - let alone video apps.

Long term - let's hope enough people push for [network neutrality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_neutrality) in the US cellular space so that there is one tariff for data based on volume - not how you intend to use that data.

Comment: Bottom line.  Cell phone companies SUCK.  SUUUCK.  Why can't Google, Microsoft, FaceBook, and about 10 giant companies through in a few $B each and create their own unlimited, super highspeed, free wireless service?  Seriously.  What would $10B be to Google and MS?  They are services companies anyway.  lol

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Buy an ipad mini from verizon.

Then go to http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VKRPkeH0-Ic

and he'll tell you how to do it. :D

Comment: You should provide the basic steps in your answer instead of only linking to external content.